# We are using jdk21 for our spring boot microservices and we are looking to upgrade to SpringBoot 3.2.3, But failing with compilation error

Tags: maven, openjdk-21

We are using jdk21 for our spring boot microservices and we are looking to upgrade to SpringBoot 3.2.3 from Spring boot 3.2.2, But mvn clean install failing with below compilation error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project commons: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: com/querydsl/apt/AbstractQuerydslProcessor
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project commons: Compilation failure

Tried upgrading dependencies ,, still no luck